# How to setup multiple identities of git ssh on windows?

Tags: git, ssh, windows-7

On my windows 7, i have created a config file that is residing in .ssh folder:-

```
Host office 
Hostname git@officeserver
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 

Host home
Hostname git@myhome.net:8888
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_home
```

but, I still unable to clone repo.

1. Wondering How would i setup multiple hosts on windows 7?
2. What should be the extension of config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hostname setup is wrong, it shouldn't have the username, only the hostname

Here an example, I am using .ssh/config to keep multiple identities (each one with different key pair) on github.com:

```
#Default GitHub
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host github-companyname.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_companyname
Host git.i411-companyname.com
  HostName git.i411-companyname.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_companyname
```

This is how your config file should look:

```
Host office 
Hostname officeserver
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 

Host home
Hostname myhome.net
User git
Port 8888
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_home
```

Note you cant include usernames or port on Hostname, you should specify those on different config variables (**User** and **Port**)

Comment: Hi Thanks..still same issue. Question: do i need to make any change in repo address while cloning?

Comment: you clone it as git@office:path/to/repo or git@home:path/to/repo